# Bootstrap - is it possible to resize an image based on the column size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am creating a picture gallery using Bootstrap. At full screen, it looks good[image: At full screen, it looks good]

At minimum size, it looks good
[image: At minimum size, it looks good]

But while re-sizing, it does this
[image: But while re-sizing, it does this]

I would like the first image (the trees) to be as wide as the second image (the lake), and I've tried adjusting width/max-width, but the problem is the image doesn't scale back down when the second image is ready to be in-line with the first image.

Is it possible to have an image be a certain width when it's col-sm-#, and a different width when it sets to col-md-#?

Comment: Show us the code you're using. If you can't include the images in the demo, can you give us the dimensions?

Comment: Sure, here is the relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/tm4d3r6w

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gkxpqn6a/1/

Comment: That did not seem to work for me.

Comment: Why? Be more specific if you want help. That makes the first image as wide as the second image.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting both as background image covers on the divs. This will allow you to resize the divs while retaining the proper aspect ratios of the images.

```
.yourdiv1{
  background: url(images/yourimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.yourdiv2{
  background: url(images/yourotherimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. That might work, but as is, the div only shows the top left corner of the image, and when I scroll down on the page, it scrolls through the image. When I re-size the window, it changes how much of the image shows, but the image itself does not re-size.